# .Net Core 2.1 expired JWT token response [Post vs Get]

Tags: api, asp.net-core, jwt

I implemented a bearer token auth for a project and it was working fine... until I noticed that when a token is expired, "get" APIs return "401 unauthorized" as it should while "post" APIs return "404 not found".

What is the reason for the post response and how to fix it?

Token config in Startup.cs

```
// add JWT authentication
services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
    .AddJwtBearer(options =>
    {
        options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
        {
            ClockSkew = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5),
            ValidateIssuer = true,
            ValidateAudience = true,
            ValidateLifetime = true,
            ValidIssuer = Configuration["JWT:issuer"],
            ValidAudience = Configuration["JWT:audience"],
            IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes((string)Configuration["JWT:key"])),
             RequireSignedTokens = true,
             RequireExpirationTime = true
        };
    });
```

Test APIs

```
[HttpGet]
[Route("api/test1")]
public IActionResult test1()
{
    return Ok("1");
}
[HttpPost]
[Route("api/test2")]
public IActionResult test2()
{
    return Ok("2");
}
```

Postman screenshot
[image: Postman screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

I have found the issue.

It looks like using custom error pages config caused the issue.

```
app.UseStatusCodePagesWithReExecute("/Error/{0}");
```

I returned it to the original config:

```
app.UseStatusCodePages();
```

and the post API started to return 401.